# Neural Network Becomes Unruly with Large Layers

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

This is a higher-level question about the performance of a neural network. The issue I'm having is that with larger numbers of neurons per layer, the network has frequent rounds of complete stupidity. They are not consistent; it seems that the probability of general success vs failure is about 50/50 when layers get larger than 60 neurons (always 3 layers).

I tested this by teaching the same function to networks with input and hidden layers of sizes from 10-200. The success rate is either 0-1% or 90+%, but nothing in between. To help visualize this, I graphed it. Failures is a total count of incorrect responses on 200 data sets after 5k training iterations. [image: imgur].

I think it's also important to note that the numbers at which the network succeeds or fails change for each run of the experiment. The only possible culprit I've come up with is local minima (but don't let this influence your answers, I'm new to this, and initial attempts to minimize the chance of local minima seem to have no effect).

So, the ultimate question is, what could cause this behavior? Why is this thing so wildly inconsistent?

The Python code is on [Github](https://github.com/stevejarvis/neural-network) and the code that generated this graph is the testHugeNetwork method in test.py (line 172). If any specific parts of the network algorithm would be helpful I'm glad to post relevant snippets.

Comment: What were your "initial attempts to minimize the chance of local minima"? Did you try just turning down the learning rate?

Comment: @larsmans What I expected to help most was initializing the weights to much smaller magnitudes (they're random). I thought larger initial values would increase the chance of the network getting stuck on the wrong path. I also experimented with learning rates and the momentum constant. None caused a noticeable change.

Comment: Interesting. Yes, small weights should help, at least if you have sigmoid (logistic or tanh) activation functions, since those tend to be linear around zero. Then again, many small sigmoid activations may add up to a very large weight going into the output layer. It that has linear activation, its predictions may be way off and training it may take a long time.

Comment: @larsmans I might have spoken too quickly. I changed both the learning rate and momentum to be even smaller than I've tried before and initial tests look good. Right now I'd say that's exactly the problem. I was so confused for days, I didn't give enough thought to the simplest variables. If that proves to be the solution, is it fairly certain the problem was local minima?

Comment: It might have been, or it might have been plateaus in the error surface, depending on how you're checking for convergence.

Comment: @jarvisteve, I clone your git project and run your test.py. I did not have that much time to wait and I just set the step size to 30 (skip=30) and get a graph like this. (http://d.pr/i/Vqi5)   Does that mean your code is performing correct? BTW, I am running under ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: Hey thanks for the update @greeness and sorry I didn't update this thread. It is fixed, the repository is working now, all I ended up doing was setting the learning rate and momentum to very low values. The coefficients were 0.5 and 0.3 respectively (I think) and they're now 0.2 and 0.1.

Comment: Good to know it's learning rate issues. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is, that your network is oscillating heavily across a jagged error surface. Trying a lower error rate might help. But first of all, there are a few things you can do to better understand what your network is doing:

- plot the output error over training epochs. This will show you **when** in the training process things go wrong.
- have a graphical representation (an image) of your weight matrices and of your outputs. Makes it much easier to spot irregularities.

A major problem with ANN training is saturation of the sigmoid function. Towards the asymptotes of both the logistic function and tanh, the derivative is close to 0, numerically it probably even *is* zero. As a result, the network will only learn very slowly or not at all. This problem occurs when the input for the sigmoid are too big, here's what you can do about it:

- initialize your weights proportional to number of inputs a neuron receives. Standard literature suggests to draw them from a distribution with mean = 0 and standard deviation 1/sqrt(m), where m is the number of input connections.
- scale your teachers so that they lie where the network can learn the most; that is, where the activation function is the steepest: the maximum of the first derivative. For tanh you can alternatively scale the function to f(x) = 1.7159 * tanh(2/3 * x) and keep the teachers at [-1, 1]. However, don't forget to adjust the derivative to f'(x) = 2/3 * 1.7159 * (1 - tanh^2 (2/3 * x)

Let me know if you need additional clarification.