# Outputs of feed-forward neural network approach 0

Tags: javascript, neural-network

I am trying to create a simple feed-forward neural network in JavaScript using a tutorial found [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-build-your-own-neural-network-from-scratch-in-python-68998a08e4f6). I believe that I followed the tutorial correctly, as when I trained it with an input matrix of `[[0,0,1],[0,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,1]]` and a solution matrix of `[[0],[1],[1],[0]]` the network performed as expected. However, when I tried to train the network using the [MNIST handwritten number database](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) and passing in larger matrices, all of the elements in the output array approached zero. I suspect that this has to do with the dot product of the input array and the weights returning an array filled with large numbers, but my attempts to scale down these number have caused the outputs to approach 1. Would anybody be able to figure out what is going wrong? My neural network has only one hidden layer with 300 neurons. The code snippet below shows the methods for my neural network, because I believe that that is where I am going wrong, but if you want to see my entire messy, undocumented program, it can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/LlamaTrauma/c70a197c123d4328cae9c71b6f08e41d). I am unfamiliar with the math library that I am using, which means that I made some of my own methods to go along with the math methods.

- multMatrices(a, b) returns the product of matrices a and b.
- math.multiply(a, b) returns the dot product of the two matrices.
- math.add(a, b) and math.subtract(a, b) perform matrix addition and subtraction, and
- transposeMatrix(a) returns the transpose of matrix a.
- setAll(a, b) performs an operation on every element of matrix a, be it plugging the element into the sigmoid function (1 / (1 + a^-e)) in the case of "sigmoid" or the sigmoid derivative function (a * (1-a)) in the case of "sigmoidDerivitive", or setting it equal to a random value between 0 and 0.05 in the case of "randomlow".

I found that setting weights to a value between 0 and 1 kept the loss at 0.9, so I set them now using "randomlow".

---

```
function NeuralNetwork(x, y){
    //Initializing the neural network
    this.input = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.sizes = [this.input._size[1], 300, this.y._size[1]];
    this.layers = this.sizes.length - 1;
    this.lyrs = [this.input];
    this.weights = [];
    this.dweights = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < this.layers; i ++){
        this.weights.push(new math.matrix());
        this.weights[i].resize([this.sizes[i], this.sizes[i + 1]]);
        this.weights[i] = setAll(this.weights[i], "randomlow");
    }
    this.output = new math.matrix();
    this.output.resize(this.y._size);
};

NeuralNetwork.prototype.set = function(x, y){
    //I train the network by looping through values from the database and passing them into this function
    this.input = x;
    this.lyrs = [this.input];
    this.y = y;
};

NeuralNetwork.prototype.feedforward = function(){
    //Looping through the layers and multiplying them by their respective weights
    for(var i = 0; i < this.weights.length; i ++){
        this.lyrs[i + 1] = math.multiply(this.lyrs[i], this.weights[i]);
        this.lyrs[i + 1] = setAll(this.lyrs[i + 1], "sigmoid");
    }
    this.output = this.lyrs[this.lyrs.length - 1];
};

NeuralNetwork.prototype.backpropogate = function(){
//Backpropogating the network. I don't fully understand this part
this.antis = [
function(a, b, c){
    return(
    math.multiply(transposeMatrix(a[0]), multMatrices(math.multiply(multMatrices(math.multiply(math.subtract(b.y, b.output), 2), setAll(b.output, "sigmoidDerivitive")), transposeMatrix(c)), setAll(a[1], "sigmoidDerivitive")))
    );
},
function(a, b, c){
    return(
    math.multiply(transposeMatrix(a[0]), multMatrices(math.multiply(math.subtract(b.y, b.output), 2), setAll(b.output, "sigmoidDerivitive")))
    );
}];
this.input = [];
this.weightInput = 0;
for(var i = this.weights.length - 1; i >= 0; --i){
    this.input.unshift(this.lyrs[i]);
    this.weightInput = (i === this.weights.length - 1 ? 0 : this.weights[i + 1]);
    this.dweights[i] = this.antis[i](this.input, this, this.weightInput);
}
for(var i = 0; i < this.dweights.length; i ++){
this.weights[i] = math.add(this.weights[i], this.dweights[i]);
}
};
```

---

As always, I appreciate any time spent trying to solve my problem. If my code is unintelligible, don't bother with it. JavaScript probably isn't the best language for this purpose, but I didn't want to follow a tutorial with the same language.

**EDIT:** This is a potential duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13500699/neural-network-becomes-unruly-with-large-layers), which was answered. If anybody is facing this problem, they should see if the answer over there is of help. As of now I have not tested it with my program.